# FInd the total and sub total in ordered item using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

when adding order i want to find the total cart of the price.
This is my code:how to find the subtotal when ordering the item.
please help me how to find this?

```
mainCtrl.controller("OrderController",function($scope,function(){
var itemlist={}
$scope.subtotal=function(){
var amount = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < $scope.itemlist.length; i++){
     angular.forEach($scope.itemlist[i].itemname, function (){
       if($scope.itemlist[i].itemname==MenuItem.itemname){
       var product = $scope.itemlist[i];
       product.qty=product.qty+1;
       amount += (product.itemprice * product.qty);
       }
     })
     console.log("this is cart amount" + amount)
     return amount;
     } 
  } 
} 
   $scope.add=function(item){
   var MenuItem={"itemid":item.itemid,"itemname":item.itemname,"itemimage":item.itemimage,"qty":1,"itemprice":item.itemprice,"subtotal":subtotal(),"tax":0,"total":$scope.subtotal()}
     var exists=false;
     angular.forEach($scope.itemlist, function (item) {
        if ((item.itemname == MenuItem.itemname)) {
            exists=true;
           item.qty++;
            return false
        }
    })
    if(!exists){
        itemlist.push(MenuItem);
        growl.success("Your Item added Sucessfully",{title:"Success"});
    }
}
})
```

Comment: may be you can use $watch.. as below

$scope.$watch('itemlist', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  // iterate through your list, calculate sum and assign it to a scope variable
 });
 });

$watch watches the item if it has been changed and invokes the logic when changed.

Comment: can you provide a working demo on plunker with sample inputs?

Comment: Why do you do a second loop on "$scope.itemlist[i].itemname", is it an array ? (the name is ambiguous)

Comment: i got the answer. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mainCtrl.controller("OrderController",function($scope,function(){
var itemlist={}

$scope.add=function(item){
var MenuItem={"itemid":item.itemid,"itemname":item.itemname,"itemimage":item.itemimage,"qty":1,"itemprice":item.itemprice,"subtotal":"","tax":0,"total":""}
 var exists=false;
 angular.forEach($scope.itemlist, function (item) {
    if ((item.itemname == MenuItem.itemname)) {
        exists=true;
       item.qty=item.qty+1;
       item.subtotal=item.qty*item.itemprice;
       item.total=item.subtotal
        return false
    }
})
if(!exists){
   MenuItem.subtotal=MenuItem.qty*MenuItem,itemprice;
   MenuItem.total=MenuItem.subtotal;
    itemlist.push(MenuItem);
    growl.success("Your Item added Sucessfully",{title:"Success"});
}
}
 })
```

Worked for me